# How to add a telephony group with OVH API

Tags: voip, telephony, ovh

I want to add a telephony group (billing account??) by using the OVH API. However, I cannot find that functionality.

One more thing: What's the difference between group, line and number.

Answer (score 1):

Well the optimal choice here is to forego the telephony group and just add the cellphony group with your OVH API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but can you elaborate more your answer please?